# How to automate the build of codenameone project (using only command line)?

Tags: codenameone

How to automate the building of a codename one project (only command line)?

Today, we need to automatize all as possible.
Is it possible to write a build pipeline for a CodeName One Project?
If yes, Which CI/CD tool is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Codename One uses a simple ant script so it's pretty easy to invoke the jar or test targets to automate the build process. This is trivial to do for every CI environment. We've used it with Google Actions, Jenkins and Travis and that's easy.

Device builds however are more complex. To do that you need the enterprise subscription since it supports synchronous builds. You can read about device build support for enterprise users in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html) under the section titled "Continuous Integration & Release Engineering".

Comment: Now that CN1 is migrating to maven, which allows users to generate builds locally, is there a way to automate the device builds for testing? Thank you.

Comment: We generate a project. The process of building the native project is a complexity of its own and that's up to you

Comment: Thank you. Is there a place  where I can find info or directions on how to do this?

Comment: Just google the process of CI for iOS and Android. There are a few commercial offerings and some pretty long tutorials on doing it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a step before the standard iOS/Android CI that is specific to CN1? Meaning, is the while process build with Maven (or Ant, for older projects) for whatever platform then the platform specific CI process? Thank you again.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but our CI doesn't work in this way so I have no experience with that